# Do SUM of Dynamic row added by innerHTML method through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do Sum on `oninput` method. Means as the button press the function will be called and show sum of two input in a paragraph `<p>` tag.

I have my javascript function like this:

```
quote:function(){

    var button = document.getElementById('insert');
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    $("#insert").click(function(){
        var position=Math.round(table.rows.length - 3);
        var row = table.insertRow(position);
        var i=1;
        row.innerHTML = '<td><input type="integer" name="qty[]" class="form-control" id="qty_' +position +'" oninput="myFunction(demo'+position+', event)"></td><td><input type="text" name="discription[]" class="form-control"></td><td><input  type="text"  name="price[]" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" id="price_'+ position+'" oninput="myFunction(demo'+position+', event)"></td><td><input  type="text" name="discount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00"><td><input  type="text"  name="discountper[]" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00%"></td></td><td><p id="demo'+position+'"></p></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="taxed[]" class="form-control"></td> <td><a class="btn btn-circle red-haze btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0);" id="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>';
        $("#remCF").live('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

    });

},
```

After append it looks like this.

[image]

I would like to calculate `Total Amount` using quantity * price.

But i am not able to do that. It seems like Rows are appending fine. But when i try to call the function i am unable to specify the text are in the `myFunction`.

here is how myFuntion looks like:

```
function myFunction(place, event) {
        var x =parseInt(document.getElementById(event.target.id).value); <!----now the problem is here i am not able to specify what QTY is clicked and which input is clicked -->
        var y= parseInt(document.getElementById(event.target.id).value); <!----now the problem is here i am not able to specify what PRICE is clicked and which input is clicked -->
        var z=x*y;
        document.getElementById(place).innerHTML = z;
}
```

I would like to perform calculation row wise.

And if for reference if you want to know how my HTML looks then here is how it looks like.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:7%;">
                Qty
            </th>
            <th style="width:50%;">
                 Description
            </th>
            <th style="width:10%;">
                Unit Price
            </th>
            <th style="width:10%;">
                Discount(Rs/$)
            </th>
            <th style="width:10%;">
                Discount%
            </th>

            <th style="width:7%;">
                Total
            </th>
            <th style="width:2%;">
                 Taxed
            </th>
            <th style="width:2%;">
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr class="odd gradeX"  id="p_scents" name="p_scnt">
            <td>
                 <input type="integer" name="qty[]" class="form-control" value="1"  id="myInput1" oninput="myFunction('demo', event)" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"   name="discription[]" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text"  name="price[]" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" id="myInput2" oninput="myFunction('demo', event)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text"  name="discount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text"  name="discountper[]" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00%">
            </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="demo"></p>
                </td>
            <td>
            <div align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="taxed[]" class="form-control"></div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr><!-- to add new column -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" >
             <div align="right">    
                <b>Sub Total:</b>
             </div> 
            </td>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" >
            <a id="insert">Add a New Service</a><br>
            <a id="ajax-demo" data-toggle="modal">
            Predifined Services </a><td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**here is the Jsfiddle link:**

https://jsfiddle.net/5xaaneor/2/

Thank you!

Comment: would you mind adding the above code to JSfiddle, So that people can easily edit it and make sure you get the solution

Comment: make a snippet or fiddle and also align your code block.

Comment: @FrayneKonok by the way how to add snippet, I see people adding it.

Comment: when you ask your question, just click on the `code block` like `<>` to add your code in the snippet. the `code block` is in the top of the bar of your question panel.

Comment: @user3201500, I must say you to use update version of jQuery.

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated for many years. What version of jQuery are you using? Also doesn't make sense setting an event handler inside another event handler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5xaaneor/1/ this is how i am using it right now....

Comment: I am using a latest version of jquery.

Comment: well look at error thrown.. `live is not a function`. It was removed from jQuery many versions ago. Use delegated version of `on()`

Comment: Ok so what can i use instead?

Comment: Strongly suggest you get away from mixing inline script and jQuery... use one or the other but since you are using jQuery already get rid of the inline script.

Comment: Yes i know i am bad at this. But i am trying to keeping it clean sir.